# XML error in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below, in a Google Sheet, from a Google Scripts book  is returning the "Illegally formed XML syntax. (line 7, file "Code")" error. What is wrong? Am new to Apps Script.

```
function helloWorldUiApp() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle(<Your Title>);
    app.add(app.createLabel('Hello World'));
    //TODO add your code here
    ss.show(app);
    }
```

Comment: The [`UiApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app) has been deprecated. Take a look at [this example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#show(Object)) instead.